# Date helper with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm wondering which Codeigniter function would be the best function to use for the gmdate php function.

The purpose of this is taking a string unix timestamp and formatting it.

Comment: Please clarify your question, what EXACTLY are you trying to do ? A code sample would be appreciated.

Comment: I refer to my post with taking a unix timestamp and formatting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have options. You can simply use original PHP function like this:

```
$utc_str = gmdate("M d Y H:i:s", time());
```

Or you can utilize `now()` function in date helper of CI, but by doing this you need to first set your `date_reference` of config to `gmt`:

```
$config['time_reference'] = 'gmt';
```

And call it like this:

```
$utc_str = date("M d Y H:i:s", now());
```

Since now() returns the current time as a Unix timestamp, referenced either to your server's local time or GMT, based on the "time reference" setting in your config file.